# setTimeout in a Promise - how to resolve and why does it only runs once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise, es6-promise

I'd like to simulate mouse scrolling based on random time, with setTimeout in a Promise. 
My goal is to keep scrolling down to the webpage's bottom: autoScroll function should be called repeatedly until it reaches the bottom, then resolve the Promise. 
Currently the code runs only once, then I got 2 errors: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: loopScroll is not defined (in browser's console)
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning (in VSCode).

```
async function loopScroll(page) { 
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500;
            setTimeout(function () {
                function autoScroll() {
                    let scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                    let currentHeight = 0;
                    let distance = 100;
                    window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                    currentHeight += distance;
                    if (currentHeight >= scrollHeight) {
                        resolve();
                    }
                }
                autoScroll();
                loopScroll(page);
            }, rand);
        });
    });
};
```

This Async - Promise thing is a little bit confusing me, I don't have too much experience with them, so I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A promise only ever gets resolved once.  The best option is just use a promise based delay function.. 'var wait = ms => new Promise((r, j)=>setTimeout(r, ms))'

Comment: `loopScroll()` is defined in the Node.js context and is not available inside `page.evaluate()` argument function that is transferred to the browser context as source code and then is recompiled there without access to the Node.js context. So you need to refactor the recursion to use only browser context functions (also you can try async for-of loop).

Comment: Maybe you're confusing `setTimeout` with `setInterval` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the first problem here is that this part of the code runs in the NodeJS environment:

```
 async function loopScroll(page) { 
   await page.evaluate(/* page environment */);
 }
```

and thats where `loopScroll` is defined in, the pages environment has no access to that function. Thats why calling `loopScroll` fails, and ends the exection.

As you are using `async` / `await` already, you don't need to use recursion at all, just `await` a loop:

```
 await page.evaluate(async () => {
  const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

  let scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
  let currentHeight = 0;
  let distance = 100;

  while(true) {
    let rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500;

    window.scrollBy(0, distance);
    currentHeight += distance;
    if (currentHeight >= scrollHeight) {
         break;
    }

   await delay(rand);
 }
});
```

Comment: For some reason it won't "break out" from the while loop after it reaches the bottom of the page. It keeps going.

Comment: @con what happens if you move the `let scrollHeight = ...` into the loop?

Comment: It works then, thank you very much! 
Could you tell me why it's working this way and why not the other (first) way?

Comment: @con I have no idea was just guessing. Try logging `scrollHeight` to find out which values it has in both cases.